# Appengine / restrict services to only be available under a single domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-appengine-node

Having multiple languages to deploy under appengine; I wonder if some kind of `private` approach could be applied; in order to have it all resides only under a single domain

For example, given `xyz.com` domain setup as wildcard; having a default service, services `svc1` and `svc2`; and a `dispatch.yaml` mapping `*/svc1/*` to `svc1` service and `*/svc2*` to svc2 service; how to :

1. hide all the `*.appspot` domain ?
2. hide the automatic setup of `svc1.xyz.com` and    `svc2.xyz.com` ?

It could be easy for a given service to check the host and redirect to the desired one; but it would have to be done for every services; feels like there a better way

It feels a bit messy to have all those auto enopoints opened and unused, the idea would be to have it all under `xyz.com/`

  -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of hiding all the routes of the `.appspot` domain. As you probably are aware the `dispatch.yaml`, only works as a redirect. Probably, you cannot just disable the default domain, since there are a lot of tools like Cloud Tasks, Cron Jobs etc.. that uses that default domain, hitting those endopoints.

As for the second question, you cannot hide them, but in case you don't need them, you can overwrite them in the `dispatch.yaml` to point to some custom made "not found" page.

Comment: can you confirm that, internally (cloudtasks, cron jobs, etc...), only the `*.appspot.com` will be used ? Am asking because if I do block `*.xyz.com` i obviously dont want to block those

Comment: If you do not specifically tell to access some subdomains blocked by you, there should be no issue